# Every operator of finite rank is compact.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Taken from Conway's A course in Functional Analysis Chapter 2 section 4 problem 2.

Problem Statement: Show that every operator of finite rank is compact.

I wanted to see if what I had below was complete. Any feedback on rigor is greatly appreciated.

Let our Hilbert space be denoted $\mathcal{H}$ and our linear operator $T$. Since $T$ is of finite rank, it maps a ball in $\mathcal{H}$. to a bounded finite dimensional set. The closure of this set is then compact, making $T$ a compact operator.

Comment: Your proof is good.

Comment: I suppose you are tacitly assuming that your operator is continuous since there are discontinuous finite rank operators which are therefore non compact.